# full text search sql server (which stackoverflow turned down)

Tags: sql-server-2008, sqlite, full-text-search, search-engine, lucene.net

My application is a help (user assistance system) just like Online MSDN. but the only way to navigation is through SEARCH. Either the search is good or my system is dead.

I am looking for a third party search engine that can connect to database and provide
out of the box full text searching.
i have researched sql server 2008 ifts, lucene.net api, sql lite fts4 but all of them lack the ranking of result as good as google does.

em not expecting sth like google but i need best ranking search engine product.

Any suggestion or experience ?

maybe i should not go for third party search engine and use Lucene.NET or sql server 2008 FTS 
but how can i establish good ranking for user provided Search query.. like

"how can i do upload excel file in XYZ interface" etc..

Comment: What do you mean by *which stackoverflow turned down*? Also note that sms speak *(em, sth)* is a good way to deter people from helping you.

Comment: I think he's referring to this article http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/stack-overflow-search-now-81-less-crappy/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My short answer is discouraging: you won't be able to find do it yourself, even for an "okay" solution.

If you want good ranking:

1. Make your site friendly to search engines (which doesn't
   necessarily mean that you have to open it to public, just make sure
   search engines understand the URLs.)
2. Pay google to do it (look for google apps)

As you said, a search engine has to do two things at least. The first one is indexing, i.e., finding the documents out of the database based on queried keywords. The second is ranking, which sorts all documents and highlights the most relevant ones.

Ranking is one of the key factor of how good a search engine is. It's not surprising ranking is hard.

To give you an idea how hard it is, take the sentence in your question (i.e., "how can i do upload excel file in XYZ interface") for example. A search engine has to answer at least two questions to get good results:

1. Which keywords is most important? For example, XYZ might be more important than the word "how", and "can".
2. What's the possible meanings of the word? "Excel" can be microsoft excel, or Xcel energy(a company name excel)

There are a whole field in computer science dedicated to this problem. If you want some more  evidences, take a quick look at ACM WWW.

One thing that is even more discouraging is that getting an "okay" solution would be difficult. The high level point is that the computer knows nothing about English, he has to read a lot to learn how to rank document.

Sadly, "a lot" means a lot of work -- For example, many textbooks suggest ranking documents based on TF/IDF, but getting a reasonable cut for these values requires crawling millions of web pages.

To summarize:

1. Ranking is hard.
2. Therefore it's not surprising that you won't be able to find any free, out-of-the-box solutions, and Google and Microsoft keep their ranking algorithms proprietary.
3. If you want to rank documents in a large database, get a search engine.

Answer (score 0):

check out new feature for semantic search in sql server 2012: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492075%28v=sql.110%29.aspx It won't be a silver bullet but might provides you a "out of the box" approach.

Comment: I have in detail checked it out. semantic search is great. But usage of the SQL Server (license costs) for static content storage and its management is costly and does not scale well.